# How Get The text on a separate line with JSOUP in Android?

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

A part of my HTML in my site (http://example.com) is:

```
//if my HTML code is:
<div class="text-co">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="">00</a>
        <a href="">11</a>
        <a href="">22</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="text-co">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="">33</a>
        <a href="">44</a>
        <a href="">55</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my android code is:

```
String url = "http://example.com";
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {

        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Elements description = document.select("div[class=title] a");
            desc = description.text();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and I want to show '**00**' in **first line** and '11' in 2th line and so on.
For example:
 00 
11
...

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 Elements description = document.select("div[class=title]");
 Elements aTags = description.select("a");
 for(Element tag : aTags) {
    String value = tag.text();
 }
```

It's work with u?

Comment: any things.so i use "**Elements description = document.select("div[class=title]").append("#"+"\\n");
     desc = description.text().replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");**" and it work for me.Tnx u for asked me............